What is the data retention limit for Tracking Extracts in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?
I am using Tracking Extract in Automation Studio in SFMC to export engagement data, such as sends, opens, and clicks. While Data Views are limited to retrieving data from the past 6 months, I noticed that when setting a custom range in Tracking Extract, it allows me to select any date, even from previous years.
Does this mean that Tracking Extract can access historical data beyond the 6-month limit in Data Views? If so, is there an actual retention period for data available via Tracking Extract, or is it dependent on other factors, such as account configuration or data storage policies?
Additionally, are there alternative native methods in SFMC for accessing long-term engagement data, particularly for historical analysis and reporting purposes?


Firstly I thank, Zuzanna for this awesome article.

Short answer: Retrieve tracking data since account inception using WSProxy.
You can retrieve 'Tracking Extract' since your SFMC instance was procured.

Details:

As we can see on the article, the time limit is only in Data views, NOT on Tracking Extract

I personally checked in SFMC, as we can see there is NOT restricted in UI as well, as I was able to successfully save this Tracking Extract activity.


